# Composite function in schwartz

Tags: schwartz-space

> Let $f(x,y)=(x-y, x+y) $ and $\varphi \in S (\mathbb R^2).$ Prove that  $\varphi \circ f \in  S(\mathbb R^2 ),$ where $S $ is the **Schwartz** space and  $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2.$

I tried to  apply

$ \forall \alpha,  \beta \in \mathbb N^d$

$|(x^{\alpha} \ D^{\beta}( \varphi \circ f)(X)$|= $|(x^{\alpha} \ D^{\beta} \varphi \circ f(X). D^{\beta}f(X)|$= $|(x^{\alpha} \ D^{\beta} \varphi (f(X)). Df(X)|$

If $\beta >1$  then $D^{\beta}f(X)=0$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You are in the right track. What you need to do is write $x^{n} y^{m}$ as $((\frac {x+y} 2 + \frac {x-y} 2)^{n} \times ((\frac {x+y} 2 -\frac {x-y} 2)^{m}$ and expand the powers using Binomial theorem.

Comment: Can I replace$ Df(X) $ by jacobian or determinant jacobian of f.